# Select values from numpy array based on other array

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

Say that I have two arrays `a` and `b`:

```
a = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]])
b = np.array([[3,1,0], [1,2,3], [3,0,2]])
```

I want to select, from each row in `a`, the item which corresponds to the highest value (within row) in `b`, i.e. I want output [1, 6, 7].

What would be a fast solution to this problem in pandas/NumPy, and would it be faster than using a for-loop in regular python? It seems very simple, but I have not found a good solution. I'm a newcomer to pandas/NumPy, but I'm thinking there must be a simple solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`np.argmax`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) with `axis=1` to get the index of each largest value in `b`'s rows,

then use advanced indexing to get the elements you want from `a`, like this:

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]])
b = np.array([[3,1,0], [1,2,3], [3,0,2]])

b_largest_idx = np.argmax(b, axis=1)

print(a[range(a.shape[0]),b_largest_idx])
```

Output:

```
[1 6 7]
```

Comment: You can use `list(range(a.shape[0]))` instead of hard-typing `[0,1,2]`.